# What modern C++ libraries should be in my toolbox?

Tags: c++

I've been out of the C++ game for about 10 years and I want to get back in and start on a commercial app.  What libraries are in use these days?

- User interface (e.g, [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [Qt](https://www.qt.io/))
- Database
- General purpose (e.g. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/), STL)
- Threading
- Testing
- Network/sockets

I looking to be cross-platform compatible (as much as possible out-of-the-box).

What libraries to do you rely on?  What features do they provide that make them *"indispensable"*?

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777764/what-modern-c-libraries-should-be-in-my-toolbox/782146#782146) below for a summary.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

**Cross-platform libraries that are free for commercial (or non-commercial) applications**

*Feel free to expand this list*

---

- General Purpose

  - [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)
  - [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net)
  - [MiLi](https://code.google.com/p/mili/)
  - [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)
  - [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_template_library) (of course)
  - [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) (STL re-implementation for extra large data sets)
  - [Qt](http://www.qt.io/)
  - [ASL](http://stlab.adobe.com/)
  - [JUCE](http://www.juce.com)

---

- Audio

  - [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/)
  - [Synthesis ToolKit](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/)
- Database

  - [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net)
  - [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/)
  - [LMDB++](http://lmdbxx.sourceforge.net/)
- Design

  - IoC Frameworks

    - [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic)
    - [PocoCapsule](http://www.pocomatic.com/docs/whitepapers/pococapsule-cpp/)
    - [Wallaroo](http://wallaroolib.sourceforge.net)
- Documents

  - [LibreOffice API](http://api.libreoffice.org/)
  - [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/)
- Graphics

  - [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/)
  - [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/)
  - [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)
- GUI

  - [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)
  - [GTK](http://www.gtkmm.org/)
  - [Qt](http://www.qt.io/)
  - [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/)
  - [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org)
  - [VTK](http://vtk.org)
- Hashing

  - [MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3)
- Imaging

  - [Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html)
  - [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net)
  - [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/)
  - [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/)
  - [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)
  - [ITK](http://itk.org)
  - [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/)
- Logging

  - [Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html)
  - [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)
  - [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/)
- Mocking

  - [Google Mock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/)
  - [Hippo Mocks](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/hippomocks)
  - [Turtle](http://turtle.sourceforge.net/) (C++ mock object library for Boost)
- Multimedia

  - [openframework](http://openframeworks.cc)
  - [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/)
  - [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)
- Networking

  - [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/%7Eschmidt/ACE.html)
  - [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)
  - [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/)
- Testing

  - [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html)
  - [Google Test](http://googletest.googlecode.com/)
  - [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/)
  - [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest)
- Threading

  - [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html)
- Version Control

  - [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/)
- Web Application Framework

  - [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/)
  - [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/)
- XML

  - [Libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/)
  - [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/)
  - [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/)
  - [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)
  - [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)

---

Links to additional lists of open source C++ libraries:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Comment: Would be cool if you show XML Libs too...

Comment: @OliverStutz I've added some XML libraries. Credit goes to [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387612/1227469) which contains an analysis of which one to use.

Comment: @JBentley thanks, i use Pugixml, figured out that this is pretty awesome, small, compileable... :-)

Comment: @@AfzaalAhmadZeeshan The Synthesis Toolkit appears to match the criteria for this question/answer, being cross-platform and free. I've  added it back in for now. Can you explain why you think it is unsuitable for this list?

Comment: I think, the boost library is the best for the general purpose.

Comment: dlib should be in this list. It works great with OpenCV and includes some state of the art algorithms.

Comment: Everybody must try all of them!

Comment: since a while *ranges-v3* is one of the first coming to my mind when asked.

Comment: Juce price list does not look free.

Answer (score 31):

Sorry for repeating some of the stuff already written, but:

- UI: [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)
- Database: [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/)
- General purpose: [Boost](http://boost.org), [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/), [STLSoft Libraries](http://www.stlsoft.org/), [ASL](http://stlab.adobe.com/)
- Threading: [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html)
- Testing: [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html)
- Build tools: [Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/index.html), [SCons](http://www.scons.org/)

(Should at least get you started)

Answer (score 11):

On Windows...

ATL for COM development
  WTL for user interface

Answer (score 10):

CGAL is an excellent c++ library for computational geometry

www.cgal.org

Answer (score 8):

http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/ might also be good addition.

It's another template library, which introduces typelists, and implementations for various design patterns.

I never used it, but I read Alexandrescu's book to get a better understanding of templates.

Comment: Loki's ScopeGuard will **change your life**. Seriously. You'll be stronger, faster, and more attractive to the opposite sex.

Answer (score 5):

CppUnit for unit testing and test driven development

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the great libraries already listed, I find the combination of xerces for XML (including XSD validation) and xalan for XSLT to be useful (xalan is built on top of xerces). AFAIK neither QT or POCO have XSLT functionality (unless it's been added since I last used them).