# High-quality libraries for C++

Tags: c++, multiplatform

We all know about [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

What other free C++ libraries are worth using? Why? Are they easily usable with common compilers?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that I believe this is a real question, but it is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777764/what-modern-c-libraries-should-be-in-my-toolbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [What modern C++ libraries should be in my toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777764/what-modern-c-libraries-should-be-in-my-toolbox)

Answer (score 5):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is a multiplatform framework that provides you not only with a great GUI toolkit, but also with [a lot of different libraries](http://qt.nokia.com/products/library/modular-class-library) and functionality that makes your life a lot easier, including a reimplementation of many standard C++ features, easing their use even further. It's heavily used in the KDE desktop environment in Linux.

It's an awesome framework. C++ almost feels like Java with it.

Answer (score 2):

Blimey .... it totally depends on what you want to do.  There are THOUSANDS of cross-platform and platform specific libraries for C++ and any one of them may or may not be useful to what you want to do.  Personally, I have found very little of actual use in boost.  Each to their own I guess but what is useful to one person is not, necessarily, useful to the next.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) XML parser. It is portable and has rich generating and validating capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is really great for anything related to computer vision

Answer (score 1):

I like [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).

Answer (score 1):

best unit testing framework by far: https://github.com/google/googletest/

Answer (score 1):

[Allegro](http://www.allegro.cc/) is my favorite for making small games.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of libraries do you have in mind? Lots of wheel reinventing can be avoided if you use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).