# is i like to have free cross platform network/thread/xml static lib

Tags: c++, free, static-libraries

what the best c++ libs that are simple to use and have no problems to compile in the windows 
express vs 2008 compilers ? 
is it best to use different libs for each purpose or to use one generic lib ?

Comment: Regarding the _static_ bit. Many C++ libraries (especially the cross-platforms ones) are offered as source tarballs so you get to choose if they are static or not when you compile them.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) has <s>all</s> two of those.

It's free, it's an industry standard, very robust, thoroughly tested, and simple to use.

For XML, many people use TinyXML.

(edit: I lied, thought Boost had XML for some reason...)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Boost for network & threading. And [xerses](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) for parsing XML. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777764/what-modern-c-libraries-should-be-in-my-toolbox) question also.

Answer (score 1):

QT has support for these.  See the [examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/examples.html), see how to [install](http://rajorshi.net/blog/2009/01/using-qt-with-msvc-express-2008/)

Answer (score 0):

- network Boost.Asio
- threading Boost.Thread
- XML tinyXML

Answer (score 0):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org) has all of it. And it's easy to use as well.